# Django admin calling the ```.save()``` method when trying to log in to the admin site

Tags: django, validation, authentication, admin, validationerror

The auth user model extends `AbstractUser` and overrides the `.save()` method. The model contains two mandatory and unique fields. It also calls `.full_clean()` in the `.save()` method. The problem arises when an admin tries to log in. Django throws a validation error saying those two fields can't be blank. The error goes away when `.full_clean()` is commented out.

Why does Django admin call the `.save()` method while trying to log in to the admin site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the `.save()` is called to store the `last_login` field for the user. This is also why it's running the validation.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer the question directly, it provides a solution.

For anyone interested, one possible work around is calling `.full_clean()` like this:

```
if not self.is_superuser: 
    self.full_clean()
```